# Error:prompt is not defined. There's a bug while trying to generate a phone number

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to create a simple program that takes an area code input from the user, generates a random phone number for them and log the full 10 digits to the console. I am getting a 'prompt is not defined error', and nothing logs after the prompt box pops up. I'm not sure why I get the prompt error since it works in the browser, but it's obvious that I have another error in my code since it isn't working in the first place.

Can anyone point out to me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance for the help!

```
function yourNum() {
    var yourNumber = '';
    var n = 0;
    var loc = parseInt(prompt('what is your area code?', 773), 10);

    if (loc.length === 3) {
        loc = '(' + loc + ')';
    }

    while (n < 7) {
        yourNumber[n] = Math.floor(Math.random() * (9));
        n++;
    }
    return loc + ' ' + yourNumber;
}

yourNum();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yourNum()` returns a number, but never prints to console or alerts. I made 3 changes to your code, and it seems to do what you want:

```js
function yourNum() {
  var yourNumber = '';
  var n = 0;
  var loc = parseInt(prompt('what is your area code?', 773), 10);

  if (loc.toString().trim().length === 3) {
    loc = '(' + loc + ')';
  }

  while (n < 7) {
    yourNumber += Math.floor(Math.random() * (9));
    n++;
  }
  console.log(loc + ' ' + yourNumber);
  alert(loc + ' ' + yourNumber);
  return loc + ' ' + yourNumber;
}

yourNum();
```

It seemed like you're trying to access `yourNumber` based on index `yourNumber[n]`. I changed it to append the number to the String through each iteration in the loop.

I added a `console.log` and `alert()` to print to console, and create a dialog box with the new number. Alertanvely, you could also `console.log(yourNum());` and remove the two lines from inside the function.

I changed `loc.length` to `loc.toString().trim().length`. `loc` is an `int` currently.

Comment: Thanks Abdul. Your method makes sense and now I see where I went wrong in my code.